# Imported Gradle project not running Main classes in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I'm a hurry to learn as much as I can about Spring due to a new project I'll working within some days, I got a demo of a book I'm thinking of buying and its source code but I can't get it working.

I can't import the projects as an "existing java project" or Maven because it has some kind of Gradle Nature, so I got Gradle plugin 2.9 for Eclipse and imported the project from the 1st chapter. The plugin hasn't come with the "Build Model" button that I found in some tutorials and I imported with the "wrapper" option checked.

The project has a class with a main method and some others with @Test that I could run with Junit but when I try to do so Eclipse doesn't show me options to run as Java Application or Junit. Trying to configure it to run manually are not working either because when I try to choose the source project the Gradle one are not listed.

I noticed the project hasn't got any facet config, but if I convert the project to has facets it comes with a lot of errors as it stops seeing its dependencies that Gradle was managing.

How can I manage this situation? Gradle may be a great tool for me to learn soon but by now I really wish I could import the projects and run without bothering with it.

If I create a new Gradle project I am able to create a class with main method and run it, curiously.

Here is where I got the projects if it is helpful

https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fourth-edition

Comment: Do you have to use Eclipse? If so, the latest version of Eclipse has Gradle support, I believe, so not sure why you had to go get the plugin

Comment: If you are set on using Spring with Gradle, perhaps this can get you started. https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but I really do not get it: somebody ready to pay your for writing an (involved, due to Spring) Java app and you cannot operate with one of the two most widely spread build tools for Java with an IDE of your choice. Forget Spring, learn how you use (build) tools first. Just a tip, IntelliJ has a much better gradle support than Eclipse, but generally Eclipse works as well (until you need to update the project).

Comment: well, thats totally ok to me. I've been working with Java for over 4 years but most of the time worked in projects with JEE + JSF 2 and now the company needs me to replace someone else in a project that uses Spring as I always showed interest in working with Spring. This project is already in development and uses Maven, so there is no urgency in learning Gradle right now. I'll take a look in IntelliJ !

Comment: I still face this problem... is that some miss conifguration ?